# Can you use Bootstraps columns when writing CSS media content?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So my question is when I'm writing CSS you can use @media and then enter a max and min width like so:

```
@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) {
#social-icons {
    padding-left: 125px;
    }
}
```

But I was wondering if you can do the same but instead of using pixels use bootstraps column method, so it would be like (min-width: col-md-3) or something like this, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can! So according to the bootstrap website you can use media queries with the grid system!

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }
/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }
/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) and (max-width: @screen-md-max) { ... }
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

This is all code from the CSS page of bootstraps website, [here.](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)